# modsecurity: SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"

Tags: apache, http

Modsecurity question...

What is the `REQUEST_METHOD` test doing in the following? It appears twice.

**`SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"`**

---

```
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "@eq 0" \
    "chain,phase:2,skip:1,t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header', severity:'2',id:'960015',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER'"
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "^$" \
    "chain,phase:2,t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header', severity:'2',id:'960015',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER'"
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@eq 0" \
    "skip:1,phase:2,t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing a User Agent Header',id:'960009',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER',severity:'4'"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "^$" \
    "t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing a User Agent Header',id:'960009',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER',severity:'4'"
SecMarker 969999
```

---

Please, don't explain the whole thing, I can read everything else. It looks like the `REQUEST_METHOD` test, however, is some sort of voodoo...

BTW, the test of the `Accept` is wrong. The `Accept` option is not mandatory as per *HTTP*.

Comment: As I was reading the docs today, I learned that the & character before a name such as REQUEST_HEADERS is used to get the count in the collection. Still wondering about the options which it seems are part of a chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the Rule **SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"** appeared twice but each time it is chained with another rule.

Chain is an action in ModSecurity that combine two or more Rules to form a single Rule.

**1st rule is now:**

```
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "@eq 0" \
   "chain,phase:2,skip:1,t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header', severity:'2',id:'960015',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER'"
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"
```

**2nd rule is now:**

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "^$" \
    "chain,phase:2,t:none,deny,log,auditlog,status:400,msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header', severity:'2',id:'960015',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER'"
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" "t:none"
```

Comment: Oh! I see! That would mean if you have no accept and no options, then boom, is that right?

Comment: Rule 1 checking for Missing Request Header but Rule 2 is checking for empty Request Header Accept i.e Accept header is present but its has no value. These two rules are doing the same thing but in a different context.